# Disable Mylocation Marker Tap in MapKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkannotation

I am adding MKAnnotationView in Apple map and make a tap event in the annotationView.But Mylocation marker is interacting the annotationView tap.How to overcome this problem.Hope you understand my problem.Thanks in advance.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var annotationView = MKAnnotationView()

    guard let annotation = annotation as? ClientLocation
        else{
            return nil
    }
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotation.identifier){
        annotationView = dequedView
    }
    else{
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.identifier)
    }
    ////////////////////////
    ///////////////////
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize your annotation view using the delegate method `viewFor annotation` from `MKMapViewDelegate`.

EDIT:

I just tried to reproduce your code, what puts me in doubt is just your class `ClientLocation`. If your `guard let` return nil you have to check this statement.

What you have to do is to check the kind of view class is coming from your delegate, like that:

```
if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
    // this means we are handling the blue point or the user location.
    //then you can set the parameters for this view like
    annotationView.canShowCallout = false

    // or even unable user to interact with
    annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Your delegate should look like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
    var annotationView = MKAnnotationView()
    guard let annotation = annotation as? ClientLocation
        else{
            return nil
    }
    if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotation.identifier){
        annotationView = dequedView
    }
    else{
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotation.identifier)
    }

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
        annotationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    ////////////////////////
    ///////////////////
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Thank you.please check my Edited question with my code

Comment: not getting it. What are you aiming ? Not show the call out for user location or not interact with it at all ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.give me some time.I will check and Accept.

Answer (score 5):

On your delegate

```
 public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        let userView = mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation)
        userView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        userView?.isEnabled = false
        userView?.canShowCallout = false
}
```

Comment: It is the only working solution I have found. Beware of breakpoints here (sometimes the blue dot was grey (iOS 15.2 simulator)). Do not put it in `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)` as it is too early

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me. Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.userLocation.title = nil
}
```